# Is a non compete clause in an offer letter enforceable in Texas?

Tags: texas, non-compete

Can a company enforce a non compete only mentioned in an offer letter in Texas ?

Suppose that the offer letter made mention of non compete/ non solicitation once: “A 6 month non-compete/solicitation is required.”

Suppose that the employee never signed a proper multi page, countersigned non compete contract. Suppose that the employee signed the one page offer letter, filled out a paper application and agreed to permit a background check company to start their process. On starting work the employee signed 3 manuals (policy, hr manual, etc).

The offer letter itself states it is not a contract of employment rather a document to communicate the job offer to the employee.

Under these circumstances, can the employer, located in Texas, enforce the 6-month non-compete provision?

Comment: Does your contract contain language akin to "*This contract supersedes and replaces any prior or contemporaneous agreements between the parties*"?

Comment: As edited, this is  question about what the law is, not a request for specific legal advice, and it should not be closed on that basis.

Answer (score 4):

It is very unlikely that such a sentence ("A 6 month non-compete/solicitation is required") is enforceable, because it is way too broad. The reasonable interpretation of the sentence is that the employer has thereby put the employee on notice that such an agreement *will be* required, and the actual terms of that agreement will be spelled out at that time, but that sentence does not constitute an "agreement". Ad actual agreement has to be supported by consideration, and have a reasonable scope (including place and activities). Texas law disfavors restrictions on job-changing, so an agreement would have to go beyond just saying that "a non-compete is required". Since the letter asserts that it is *not* a contract, there is no clear contractual obligation (they can fire you anytime they want, it seems).